# Splitting a string composed of numbers and alphabets

Tags: java

I want to break a string like :

```
String s = "xyz213123kop234430099kpf4532";
```

into tokens where each token starts with an alphabet and ends with a number. So the above string can be broken down into 3 tokens :

```
xyz213123
kop234430099
kpf4532
```

This string `s` could be very big but the pattern will remain the same, i.e each token will start with 3 alphabets and end with a number.

How do I split them ?

Comment: Use [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: You should be able to split them with a fancy regex, but I never get the non-consuming regexes right in my head. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\w+?\d+
```

Java **Matcher**:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+?\\d+"); //compiles the pattern we want to use
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("xyz213123kop234430099kpf4532"); //we create the matcher on certain string using our pattern

while(matcher.find()) //while the matcher can find the next match
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); //print it
}
```

And then you could use **Regex.Matches** C#:

```
foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches("xyz213123kop234430099kpf4532", @"\w+?\d+"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

And for the future this:

[RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: You can use that with a Matcher.  Perhaps you can include how. btw `+?` is the same as `*`

Comment: Can you write that in Java?

Comment: @PeterLawrey It is not the same, check it on the link I have provided with the string saplingPro gave us.

Comment: You are right that `+?` and `*` are different.  In particular `+?` is reluctant which means it starts matching the `\\d` when it can.

Comment: @PeterLawrey added also the comments to Java code, anyway if you would like to get some nice knowledge about Regex in no time check this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this,

```
String s = "xyz213123kop234430099kpf4532";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+?\\d+");
    Matcher match = p.matcher(s);
    while(match.find()){
        System.out.println(match.group());  
    }
```

#### OUTPUT

```
xyz213123
kop234430099
kpf4532
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start from such regexp: (\w+?\d+)
http://regexr.com?36utt

Comment: '+?' is the same as `*` and I don't think its appropriate here. Can you show how to use this regex in Java?

Comment: I should have googled it and it turns out `+?` is described as reluctant.